# How to give image on selected cell in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to set image on cell .When i select that cell then only i want to pass image on it i have 3 section in tableview,
first section i have 1row.Second section i have 3row and third section i have 1 row so how to call selected image on cell .If i cliked any cell

i try thi code but it working but i am showing lable also with red color if this view appear on cell background then it hide the label bacground red color only i can see text which is coming on that label but label background color i can't see why this happen .
i put this code in cellfor row at indexpath method

```
UIView *viewSelected = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
viewSelected.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = viewSelected;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can accomplish this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.....

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
switch ([indexPath.section]) {
    case 0:
    {
       switch ([indexPath.row]) {
           case 0:
           {
             [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"]];
            break;
           }
       break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the section using the check

```
if (indexPath.section == 0){
  //perform selection of section 0
}
else if (indexPath.section == 1){
  //perform selection of section 1
}
else if (indexPath.section == 2){
  //perform selection of section 2
  //Also do the selection of particular row

  if (indexPath.row == 0){
     //perform selection of row 0 section 2
   }
}
```